# Palette to copy and paste cell reference number

Tags: cells, palettes

I have the following palette:

```
CreatePalette[Column[
   (Button[Style[#1, 20, FontFamily -> 
              "Calibri"], FrontEndTokenExecute[
            InputNotebook[], "Style", #1], 
          Appearance -> "Palette", 
          ImageSize -> 250] & ) /@ 
     {"Title", "Subtitle", "Subsubtitle", 
       "Section", "Subsection", 
       "Subsubsection", "Text", 
       "DisplayFormula", 
       "DisplayFormulaNumbered"}, 
   Spacings -> 0]];
```

I want to add two extra buttons to the bottom of the palette:

1. A button that copies the number of a formula in the selected `DisplayFormulaNumbered` cell;
2. A button that pastes this as a reference wherever I choose (ideally in brackets).

I do have a palette which copies cell references:

```
CreatePalette[Button["Copy cell ref", 
 Module[{cell, tags, tag, createTag}, 
   cell = First[Cells[NotebookSelection[
            InputNotebook[]], CellStyle -> 
            "DisplayFormulaNumbered"], 
        MessageDialog[
           "Select an equation cell!"]; 
         Return[]]; tags = Replace[
        CurrentValue[cell, CellTags], 
        t : Except[_List] :> {t}]; 
    createTag := With[
        {newTag = CreateUUID["eqnID-"]}, 
        SetOptions[cell, CellTags -> 
             Append[Select[tags, Not @* 
                   StringMatchQ["eqnID-*"]], 
               newTag]]; newTag]; 
    tag = SelectFirst[tags, StringMatchQ[
          "eqnID-*"], createTag]; 
    If[Length[Cells[InputNotebook[], 
            CellTags -> tag]] > 1, 
      MessageDialog["Multiple cells with same \
 tag found!\n     Tag of current cell will be \
 regenerated."]; tag = createTag]; 
    With[{tag = tag}, CopyToClipboard[
        Button[Row[{"(", Dynamic[CurrentValue[
                  First[Cells[CellTags -> tag], 
                    $Failed], {"CounterValue", 
                    "DisplayFormulaNumbered"}]], 
              ")"}], Appearance -> None]]]]], 
 Saveable -> False, WindowTitle -> 
 "Equation linking"]
```

...but I can't figure out how to add this functionality to the first palette, and add the Paste function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stylebuttons = (Button[Style[#1, 20, FontFamily -> "Calibri"], 
      FrontEndTokenExecute[InputNotebook[], "Style", #1], 
      Appearance -> "Palette", ImageSize -> 250] &) /@ {"Title", 
    "Subtitle", "Subsubtitle", "Section", "Subsection", 
    "Subsubsection", "Text", "DisplayFormula", 
    "DisplayFormulaNumbered"};

button2 = Button[Style["Copy cell ref", 20, FontFamily -> "Calibri"], 
   Module[{cell, tags, tag, createTag}, 
    cell = First[Cells[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], 
       CellStyle -> "DisplayFormulaNumbered"], 
      MessageDialog["Select an equation cell!"];
      Return[]]; 
    tags = Replace[CurrentValue[cell, CellTags], 
      t : Except[_List] :> {t}];
    createTag := With[{newTag = CreateUUID["eqnID-"]}, 
      SetOptions[cell, 
       CellTags -> Append[Select[tags, Not@*StringMatchQ["eqnID-*"]], newTag]]; 
      newTag];
    tag = SelectFirst[tags, StringMatchQ["eqnID-*"], createTag];
    If[Length[Cells[InputNotebook[], CellTags -> tag]] > 1, 
     MessageDialog["Multiple cells with same  tag found!\n     Tag of current cell \
will be  regenerated."]; tag = createTag];
    With[{tag = tag}, 
     CopyToClipboard[Button[Row[{"(", 
         Dynamic[CurrentValue[First[Cells[CellTags -> tag], $Failed], {"CounterValue", 
            "DisplayFormulaNumbered"}]], ")"}], 
       Appearance -> None]]]], Appearance -> None];

 pastebutton = Button[Style["Paste", 20, FontFamily -> "Calibri"], Paste[], 
      Appearance -> None];
```

Combine the buttons using `Join`:

```
CreatePalette[Column[Join[stylebuttons, {button2, pastebutton}], 
  Spacings -> 0, Alignment -> Center], 
 Saveable -> False,  WindowTitle -> "Cell Styles & Cell Ref"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @kglr.Is it possible to make the last two buttons look the same as the rest?

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward, please see the updated version.

Comment: Fantastic. Many thanks.